# Random letter and value Powerpoint VBA

Tags: vba, random, numbers, powerpoint, letter

I'm trying to obtain a random generated output with this kind of options:

Firstly a letter which could be R or L
Secondly a number that could only be 15, 30, 45 or 60.

For example an output could be R45 or L15.
All this should be generated randomly every time the slide is opened.

I tried with this code but without results, no output appears in the label. Can someone give me a hint?

```
signA = "R"
signB = "L"
cont = Int(Rnd * 100) + 1
Angle = Int(Rnd * 120) + 1

valore = cont Mod 2
If valore = 0 Then
    If Angle <= 30 Then
        vardec = "15"
        var = signA & vardec
    Else
        If Angle <= 60 Then
            vardec = "30"
            var = signA & vardec
        Else
            If Angle <= 90 Then
                vardec = "45"
                var = signA & vardec
            Else
                vardec = "60"
                var = signA & vardec
            End If
        End If
    End If
Else
    If Angle <= 30 Then
        vardec = "15"
        var = signA & vardec
    Else
        If Angle <= 60 Then
            vardec = "30"
            var = signA & vardec
        Else
            If Angle <= 90 Then
                vardec = "45"
                var = signA & vardec
            Else
                vardec = "60"
                var = signA & vardec
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes("Label2").OLEFormat.Object.Caption = CStr(var)
```

Comment: What appears if you show an output in the message box? Just add on the end MsgBox(CStr(var)) ...

Comment: I tryed adding MsgBox(CStr(var)) at the and but no message box appears! I have no output..

Comment: No message box or a message box with nothing in? I think, a message box should be shown  :)

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem! Var was mistakenly set as Integer, now it works :) Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions actually work, i tested it on a text label, just check you're referencing the label correctly.